# Discord bot now working with events, How to fix?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I think my bot doesn't work because of the two events.

I'm making a bot that if I type `IP` or `ip` it would say the server address and if I do `!!staff` it would display the staff list but the problem is if I type `ip` or `IP` it wouldn't work

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!")
client = discord.Client().

@bot.command()
async def staff(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Mineprison Staff team", description="Dit is het staff team", color=0x39aa31)
    embed.add_field(name="Owners", value="jasper2502, TheArchitectnl", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Manager", value="BastiaanBcraft", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Helpers", value="ItsJeBoyGoogle, Aangepast, MikaySoldier", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Gemaakt door ItsJeBoyGoogle")
    

    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
@bot.listen
async def on_message(message):
    """ some on_message command """
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    msg_content = message.content.lower()
    ip = ['ip', 'IP']

    if any(word in msg_content for word in ip):
        await message.channel.send("Het ip is XXXXXX")        


# EXECUTES THE BOT WITH THE SPECIFIED TOKEN. TOKEN HAS BEEN REMOVED AND USED JUST AS AN EXAMPLE.
bot.run('XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
```

Output:

The `!!staff` command works but the `on_message` gives me this error:

```
Ignoring exception in command None:
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandNotFound: Command "ip" is not found and leaving me with no response in the discord channel
```

Comment: Because there's not a command called `ip`. You shouldn't make "commands" inside the `on_message` event.

Comment: shouldn't be `@bot.event` instead of `@bot.listener` ? Or maybe even without `@bot.listener` ? But if you change `on_message` then it may not work `command` because original `on_message` recognizes command and runs assigned  function. And it would need `super().on_message(message)` inside `def on_message(message):`

Comment: if your code will work then may gives IP even when you write message `abcIPdef`. You should rather check `msg_content == word`

Comment: if you convert `message.content.lower()` then you can check only `ip` - there is no need to check `IP`

Comment: if you use `Bot` then you don't need `Client` because `Bot = Client + command + other`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use `IP` without `!!` you would have to use `@bot.event` on `on_message` to run this code.

But `bot` already uses own `on_message` to run `commands` and when you create own `on_message` then it will not run `commands`. It needs `await bot.process_commands(message)` in own `on_message` to run `commands`.

```
import os
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!")

@bot.command()
async def staff(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Mineprison Staff team", description="Dit is het staff team", color=0x39aa31)
    embed.add_field(name="Owners", value="jasper2502, TheArchitectnl", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Manager", value="BastiaanBcraft", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Helpers", value="ItsJeBoyGoogle, Aangepast, MikaySoldier", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Gemaakt door ItsJeBoyGoogle")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
    
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    """ some on_message command """
    
    print('[DEBUG] message:', message)
    
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    
    msg_content = message.content.lower()
    
    if msg_content == 'ip':
        await message.channel.send("Het ip is XXXXXX")        
        return  # skip other commands

    # runs commands like !!staff     
    await bot.process_commands(message)   

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
print('TOKEN:', TOKEN)
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

---

**BTW:**

If you use `Bot` then you don't need `Client` because `Bot = Client + commands + other`

If you convert message to lower then you can check only `ip` - you don't need to check `IP`

If you check `"ip" in msg_content` then it may gives answer also for messages like `xxxipxxx`. Maybe you should check `"ip" == msg_content` or split messages to words and check every word separatelly. All depend on what you really want to get.

---

**EDIT:**

Eventually you can create normal `bot.command()` which runs with `!!ip` and in `on_message` add `!!` (or `bot.command_prefix`) when you get message `ip`.

```
import discord
import os
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!!")

@bot.command()
async def staff(ctx):
    embed=discord.Embed(title="Mineprison Staff team", description="Dit is het staff team", color=0x39aa31)
    embed.add_field(name="Owners", value="jasper2502, TheArchitectnl", inline=True)
    embed.add_field(name="Manager", value="BastiaanBcraft", inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name="Helpers", value="ItsJeBoyGoogle, Aangepast, MikaySoldier", inline=True)
    embed.set_footer(text="Gemaakt door ItsJeBoyGoogle")
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

@bot.command()
async def ip(ctx):
    await ctx.channel.send("Het ip is XXXXXX")        
    
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    """ some on_message command """
    
    print('[DEBUG] message:', message)
    
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    
    msg_content = message.content.lower()
    
    if 'ip' == msg_content:
        #message.content = '!!' + msg_content
        message.content = bot.command_prefix + msg_content


    await bot.process_commands(message)   

TOKEN = os.getenv('DISCORD_TOKEN')
print('TOKEN:', TOKEN)
bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thanks furas you really helped me there, Thank you so much!! <3
And thanks everybody that helped me ! thumbs up! <3

- ItsJeBoyGoogle